# Pass a list of string from Django to Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, unicode

My Django objects have an attribute "City". I'm trying to get a list of cities and catch it in the template with Jquery (to use in a chart on the X axis).
**My problem is that I can't get rid of the unicode and quote for a list.**
(I manage to do it for one single value). Instead I'm stucked with this:
["[[u'Paris'], [u'Lyon']]"]

I've tried tons of things, included JSON. No success.

**My view:**
(actually, one of many try..)

```
def barchart1(request):
    city_array =[]
    for i in [1,MyObject.objects.count()]:
        objet = get_object_or_404(MyObject, pk=i)

        cities = [objet.city.city_name]
        city_array.append(cities)

return render (request, 'plot3/plot_page.html', {"city_array" : city_array})
```

**My JS:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var cities = ["{{ city_array }}"];
</script>
```

**Here is how JS read the context sent by the view**
["[[u'Paris'], [u'Lyon']]"]

**Here is what I would like to get**
['Paris', 'Lyon']

It MUST be something simple but I just couldn't figure out how to do it.
Others posts don't deal with a list of string.

Any idea of what should I do?

Comment: What did not work when you tried json?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

When you do `{{ city_array }}` in your template, your list is converted to a string. This is done by calling `repr()` on the list, which recursively calls `repr()` on its contents. Because your strings are unicode, you see those unicode literals, `u'Paris'`.

The "correct" way to do this is to encode your data to json, for example in your view:

```
import json
# ...
json_cities = json.dumps(city_array)
# ...
return render (request, 'plot3/plot_page.html', {"city_array" : json_cities})
```

and then do

```
var cities = {{ city_array|safe }};
```

in the template.

Please note: **don't use this for user-controller data!** See the [XSS Cheat Sheet by OSWASP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet) and the discussion on [Django ticket 17419](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/17419) for further information. To prevent XSS, you could use something like the [SafeJSONEncoder from the django-cms project](https://github.com/divio/django-cms/blob/develop/cms/utils/encoder.py).

Comment: Perfect that worked! Actually, I tried something similar but I didn't put |safe. How does it work ?
After 4 hours, your help was welcome!

Comment: The `safe` template filter is a way to disable Django's built-in HTML escaping, which is a way to prevent [XSS attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting). You can read more [in the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/#automatic-html-escaping), but at least keep this in mind: only use `safe` if you are absolutely sure that no untrusted user input will end up unescaped in the output (in this case, `json.dumps(...)` takes care of it for you).

Comment: @sana I'm afraid I was wrong about XSS safety of `json.dumps` - please see the edit!